# internet explorer won't play webm video files?

Tags: html, video

I have installed [a webm plugin](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/webmmf) for internet explorer but internet explorer 9 won't play the webm file. IE only downloads it.

Is there any way to prevent this like('event.preventDefault')?

Comment: what version of IE are you using ??

Comment: i have installed the latest version available on the microsoft's website

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that You are using IE9+
because if you look [here](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/webmmf) you will see
"WebM Video for Microsoft Internet Explorer 9 "

Comment: as i commented above i have installed the most latest internet explorer version available

Comment: what do you mean by the most recent , be more specific 
and mention the version you are using

Comment: internet explorer 9